# Docker deployment error: root - how to fix?

Tags: docker, deployment, stack

(I'm like a beginner to Docker/Linux/etc.). Trying to get Heimdall working, but getting the error:

> deployment error failed to deploy a stack: root additional property Heimdall is not allowed

This is the stack I'm trying to deploy:

```
heimdall:
  image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/heimdall
  container_name: heimdall
  environment:
    - PUID=1000
    - PGID=1000
    - TZ=Netherlands/Amsterdam
  volumes:
    - /home/me/docker/heimdall/config:/config
  ports:
    - 11080:80
    - 11443:443
  restart: always
```

Also added the "docker" user to my username group.

Hope someone can give me some insight about this.

Kind regads.

Comment: Is that the entire file?  It looks like the archaic "version 1" Compose format, without a  `services:` key, and the most current versions of Compose no longer support it.

Comment: The file you show - which code is trying to read it and giving you the error? What is the command line you invoke?